# Rename sheet with two separate variables

Tags: excel, vba

I work in manufacturing and I'm looking to speed up the reports I have to submit. The problem I'm working on is copying the existing worksheet to the end of the workbook and then renaming the worksheets based on the previous one.

For example, the first sheet could be named `R113 D2` and I would like to copy it and rename it as `R113 D9`. Then when copying the `R113 D9` sheet, I would like it renamed as `R114 D2`.

```
Sub CopySheetRename()

    Sheets.Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
    On Error Resume Next
    ActiveSheet.Name = 'This is where I'm stuck and don't know what to do
    On Error GoTo 0

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub CopySheetRename()
    ' Sheets(1) is the first sheet
    Sheets(1).Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
    ' Concat cell R113 and cell D2 as sheet name
    ActiveSheet.Name = [R113] & [D2]
    ActiveSheet.Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
    ActiveSheet.Name = [R113] & [D9]
    ActiveSheet.Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
    ActiveSheet.Name = [R114] & [D2]
End Sub
```

---

> Question: Is a way to make is more dynamic?

```vb
Option Explicit
Sub CopySheetRename()
    Dim sShtName As String
    Dim sName1 As String, sName2 As String
    Dim c As Range, iLoc As String
    With Sheets(1)
        .Select
        iLen2 = Len(Trim(.Cells(2, "D").Value))
        sShtName = Sheets(Sheets.Count).Name
        If sShtName = .Name Then
            ' Only one sheet in workbook
            sName1 = "R1"
            sName2 = "D2"
       Else
            iLoc = VBA.InStr(sShtName, " ")
            ' sheet name part 1
            sName1 = Left(sShtName, iLoc - 1)
            ' sheet name part 2
            sName2 = Mid(sShtName, iLoc + 1)
            If sName2 = "D2" Then
                sName2 = "D9"
            ElseIf sName2 = "D9" Then
                sName2 = "D2"
                ' part 1 number + 1
                sName1 = Left(sName1, 1) & CInt(Mid(sName1, 2)) + 1
            Else
                MsgBox sName2 & " doesn't match D2 or D9."
                Exit Sub
            End If
        End If
        ' Copy sheet and rename
        .Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
        ActiveSheet.Name = sName1 & " " & sName2
    End With
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Is a way to make is more dynamic, where as i continue copying throughout the year as the R value keeps increasing? for example if R =113 and D = 2, then new sheet name is R=113 and D =9, else R=114 and D =2? the R number will always go up by 1 once there is a D2 and D9. Sorry if I'm not very clear.

Comment: How many copies do you need? Does it always start from 113? If not, how to determine the start row?

Comment: It one day started at R1 D2, then R1 D9, basically the production run is based off a two week cycle, and I run the same report twice each two week cycle. When I started the reports started at R89 and now it's at R113. The D value will always be either 2 or 9, but the R value increases by one each time it completes a D2 and D9 loop.

Comment: I have updated the code.

Comment: Good Morning, when I run the code the new sheet is renamed R113 D2 (2), any suggestions?

Comment: What's the first sheet name and the last sheet name before running the code? Do you use a space as seperator in sheet name?

Comment: Last sheet name is R113 D2, would like to code to run the have a sheet named R113 D9, then if I run the code again R114 D2. Yes the space is a seperator in the sheet name

Comment: There sheetname has two parts which is seperated with a space.  Both parts have same patter: `one letter (R/D) + a nubmer`. Is it correct?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: I have updated the code. Please try.

Answer (score 0):

### Add Sheets Incrementally With a Step

**Before**

[image]

**After**

[image]

**Main**

```vb
Sub AddNewIncrementedSheet()
    Const PROC_TITLE As String = "Add New Incremented Sheet"
    Dim WasSuccess As Boolean
    Dim dws As Worksheet
    On Error GoTo ClearError
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Worksheets(wb.Worksheets.Count)
    
    Dim dwsName As String
    dwsName = GetNextIncrementedString(sws, "R", " D", "2", "9")
    ' or:
    'dwsName = GetNextIncrementedString(ws:=sws, LeftDelimiter:="R", _
        RightDelimiter:=" D", RightStayString:="2", RightIncrementString:="9")
    
    If Len(dwsName) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "The worksheet name """ & sws.Name & """ is inconsistent!", _
            vbCritical, PROC_TITLE
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Dim dsh As Object
    On Error Resume Next
        Set dsh = wb.Sheets(dwsName)
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    If Not dsh Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "A sheet named """ & dwsName & """ already exists!", _
            vbCritical, PROC_TITLE
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    sws.Copy After:=sws
    Set dws = sws.Next
    dws.Name = dwsName
    
    WasSuccess = True
    
ProcExit:
    On Error Resume Next
        If WasSuccess Then
            MsgBox "Added worksheet """ & dwsName & """ (after worksheet """ _
                & sws.Name & """).", vbInformation, PROC_TITLE
        Else
            If Not dws Is Nothing Then
                Application.DisplayAlerts = False ' delete without confirmation
                    dws.Delete
                Application.DisplayAlerts = True
            End If
        End If
    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Sub
ClearError:
    MsgBox "Run-time Error '" & Err.Number & "':" & vbLf & vbLf _
        & Err.Description, vbCritical, PROC_TITLE
    Resume ProcExit
End Sub
```

**Help**

Conditions

- The string starts with the left delimiter.
- There is an integer between the left and right delimiters.
- The integer will be incremented if the substring after the right delimiter is equal to the increment string.
- The stay string will become the increment string and vice versa.

```vb
Function GetNextIncrementedString( _
    ByVal ws As Worksheet, _
    ByVal LeftDelimiter As String, _
    ByVal RightDelimiter As String, _
    ByVal RightStayString As String, _
    ByVal RightIncrementString As String) _
As String
    
    Dim lLen As Long: lLen = Len(LeftDelimiter)
    Dim rLen As Long: rLen = Len(RightDelimiter)
    
    Dim rStr As String: rStr = ws.Name
    Dim Pos As Long: Pos = InStr(rStr, LeftDelimiter)
    If Pos <> 1 Then Exit Function ' doesn't begin with right delimiter
    If Left(rStr, lLen) <> LeftDelimiter Then Exit Function ' doesn't begin with
    
    rStr = Right(rStr, Len(rStr) - lLen)
    Pos = InStr(rStr, RightDelimiter)
    If Pos < 2 Then Exit Function ' space (0) or number (1) not found
    
    Dim lStr As String: lStr = Left(rStr, Pos - 1)
    If Not IsNumeric(lStr) Then Exit Function ' not numeric
    
    rStr = Right(rStr, Len(rStr) - Len(lStr) - rLen)
    
    Select Case rStr
        Case RightStayString: rStr = RightIncrementString ' stay
        Case RightIncrementString: rStr = RightStayString
            lStr = CStr(CLng(lStr) + 1) ' increment
        Case Else: Exit Function ' neither
    End Select
    
    GetNextIncrementedString = LeftDelimiter & lStr & RightDelimiter & rStr
    
End Function
```